# Add logo in qrcodejs

Tags: javascript, qr-code

I want to add My logo to a QR Code and I am using the following library - [Qrcodejs](https://github.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/).

And I am using the following code -

```
    var qrcode = new QRCode(re, {
        text: inp.value,
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        colorDark : "#5868bf",
        colorLight : "#ffffff",
        correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
    });
```

I researched on how to add logo, but got the results for other libraries, but I want this library only.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it yourself:

- Load the generated PNG into a canvas
- Draw your image into the exact center with a width and height of at
  most 1/3 of the QR code size

[QRcode logo](https://github.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/issues/131)

Or try:

```
this.qrcode = new QRCode(document.getElementById('qrcode'), {
      logo: logoLink,
      text: link,
      width: 256,
      height: 256,
      colorDark: '#000000',
      colorLight: '#ffffff',
      correctLevel: QRCode.CorrectLevel.H,
      logoWidth: undefined,
      logoHeight: undefined,
      logoBackgroundColor: '#ffffff',
      logoBackgroundTransparent: false,
    });
```

[logo](https://github.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/issues/245)

Comment: [https://github.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/issues/131#issuecomment-647489077] (I tried this) but got the follow error - Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLCanvasElement or HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas or SVGImageElement or VideoFrame)'.
    at imgQR (main.js:54)
    at HTMLInputElement.sub.onclick (main.js:44).